# Why the reference can be passed into the function receiving a trait?

Tags: rust

There is such piece of code:

```
struct A<T> {
    w: T,
}

impl<T: std::fmt::Display> std::fmt::Display for A<T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        self.w.fmt(f)
    }
}

fn func(a: impl std::fmt::Display + std::ops::Deref) {
    println!("func {}", a);
}

fn main() {
    let a = A { w: 33 };
    func(&a);
}
```

What I really does not understand it is why the reference on A object can be passed in the function. Does that mean that a reference automatically implements all the traits that the pointed object implements? If it is so, where can I find the rule?

Moreover it behaves in the similar way with the smart pointers like Box and Rc.

First, I thought it could be a "deref coercion". Therefore if the compiler notes that passed type does not correspond to the specified one in a function prototype, rust tries casting of the passed object to the required type by the deref(). So it could deref the reference and get containing type, that implement Display trait. But then I realised that it can't be true because struct A does not implement the Deref trait (I added Deref bound later).

So if I can specify in a function prototype a trait 'by value' and pass just reference, what is the best practices for that case? Should I receive a reference or just a trait?

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: &T is a type in of itself, and may implement traits. In particular, Display is implemented for any &T where T implements Display.

Comment: "&T is a type in of itself, and may implement traits" - Yes I know. The question was: why the reference, Box and Rc implement Display trait.
"In particular, Display is implemented for any &T where T implements Display" -
Thank you. Where can I find the rule? Is it true only for Display or for any other trait?

Comment: It is listed in documentation for Display.

Comment: I found it, thanks!
`impl<T> Display for &mut T
where
    T: Display + ?Sized,
`

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of deref coercion. It is because `Display` is implemented in the standard library [`&Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-for-%26T), [`&mut Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/std/fmt/trait.Display.html#impl-Display-for-%26mut+T), [`Box<Display>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1859-1863), [`Rc<Display>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#1887-1891) and [`Arc<Display>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.70.0/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#2590-2594), where `Display` is some type that implement `Display`.